# Two different notations used for a preorder relation

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

A preorder relation $R$ is a homogeneous binary relation over $X$ satisfying the reflexivity and transitivity property,e.g. for all $a,b,c \in R$:

$$a\le a \;\text{(reflexivity)}$$
$$\text{If} \; a\le b \;\text{and}\; b\le c \; \text{then }\;  a\le c\;\text{(transitivity)}$$

The problem I have is that I cannot fully understand what does the notation $\le$ mean, and I think it's not **necessarily** the usual definition of its meaning which is less or equal to( greater than or equal to).

For example given a set $X=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ ,  if we define the preorder relation to be "$⊆$", then $\left\{1,2\right\}\le\left\{1,2,3\right\}$, but clearly translating the notation $\le$ as the usual meaning won't give a good concept, but based on what we defined it can be said that :
$$\left\{1,2\right\}\; \;\text{is a subset of}\; \;\left\{1,2,3\right\}$$

But some authors suggest using the notation $\lesssim$.

But why we don't use the previous notation? 
Also wikipedia says :

> Given a preorder $≲$ on $S$ one may define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$ such that $a \sim b$ if and only if $a ≲ b$ and $b ≲ a$.
>   Why this statement holds?
>   For example define $S:=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and let the equivalence $\sim$ be defined such that:$$\sim:=\left\{\left(1,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right),\left(1,3\right),\left(3,1\right)\right\}$$

We conclude that $1\sim2$, so what does it mean to say $1≲2$ and $2≲1$?

Another statement is as follows:

> We have $a ≲ b$ if and only if $a < b$ or $a \sim b$. This is the reason for using the notation $"≲"$; $"≤"$ can be confusing for a preorder that is not antisymmetric

Can someone explain why this may cause some confusion?

Comment: Note:  you could define a binary operation $a\times b$ but it could be something different from usual multiplication

Comment: As an aside, it is also common for people to use $\prec$ and $\preceq$ (*typed as `\prec` and `\preceq`*) for partial orders / pre-orders and such if it is meant to be emphasized that it may not necessarily match with any preexisting common partial orders such as the usual $\leq$ of the real numbers or $\subseteq$ of sets but that they share some of the common properties of partial orders in much the same way that $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ might be used to represent something "like" addition or "like" multiplication.

Comment: @JMoravitz,Wikipedia states "we have $a ≲ b$ if and only if $a < b$ or $a \sim b$", a preorder is a binary relation  satisfying reflexivity, transitivity property, it may be antisymmetry or it may be symmetry , but in my opinion the statement is not true since a preorder may be asymmetry , in this situation the preorder relation is neither $\sim$ nor $<$

Comment: It is worth reminding that preorders don't need to be antisymmetric and don't need to be symmetric.  It could be neither, or it could be both, or it could be one or the other.  Knowing that $a\lesssim b$ we have no way of knowing whether or not $b\lesssim a$ without looking deeper at how the relation is defined in the first place.  "*What does it mean to say $1\lesssim 2$ and $2\lesssim 1$?*"  It means that both $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are pairs in the relation.

Comment: As for $\lesssim$ as it relates to $\sim$ and $<$., the linked text explains how we define $\sim$ from what we know about $\lesssim$.  As for how to define $<$ from $\lesssim$ that follows from the if and only if definition given above.  $a<b$ is being defined here as simultaneously $a\lesssim b$ and $a\not\sim b$.  You can show that defining $<$ in this way does give rise to a strict partial order which is antisymmetric, even if $\lesssim$ is not itself antisymmetric.

Comment: so it means the preorder besides satisfying reflexivity, transitivity also satysfies  symmetry which means it's an equivalence relation but not necessarily **just** an equivalence relation, right?

Comment: No, preorders do not need to be symmetric. Nothing JMoravitz said indicates that in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to show some examples of preorders. Here are all the preorders that can be placed on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and have 5 or fewer elements, plus at least some of the 6 element preorders (I am not sure if there are more - I just got tired of working it out). I've also noted which are symmetric, which are anti-symmetric, and which are neither:

- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}$ - symmetric ("$=$")
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,1)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,1)\}$ - symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,3), (3,1)\}$ - symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,3), (3,2)\}$ - symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (1,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1), (2,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,1), (3,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,3), (2,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (3,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1), (3,1)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric ("$\le$")
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,3),(3,2),(1,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1),(1,3),(2,3)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,3),(3,1),(2,1)\}$ - anti-symmetric
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,2),(2,1),(3,1)\}$ - anti-symmetric ("$\ge$")
- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,1),(1,2),(3,2)\}$ - anti-symmetric

Because all of those are either symmetric or anti-symmetric, let me add one more:

- $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(3,2)\}$ - neither

All of these are reflexive and transitive, so they are pre-orders. The ones that are symmetric are equivalence relations. The ones that are anti-symmetric are partial orders (in fact, the last set are all total orders). But it is possible for a pre-order to be neither one, as the final example shows.

Comment: @First of all thank you so much for this effort (+1), I got your point, and so we can say a preorder is a generalization of both equivalence relation and partial order, also can we say $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2)\}$ is an asymmetric relation too? because $1\sim2$ holds but $2\sim1$ does not hold.

Comment: That depends on how you define "asymmetric". If by asymmetric, you just mean "not symmetric", then yes. If you mean "neither symmetric or anti-symmetric", then no, since it is anti-symmetric.

Comment: should not it be "nor" instead of "or"? and can you tell me why the sentence " We have $a ≲ b$ if and only if $a < b$ or $a \sim b$." is true?

Comment: ?? how does that make any sense at all? $\le$ is called "less than *or* equal to" not "less than nor equal to".

Comment: The definition of $a \sim b$ is $a ≲ b$ and $b ≲ a$. The definition of $a < b$ is $a ≲ b$ and not $b ≲ a$. So if $a ≲ b$ is true, then either $b ≲ a$ is true, in which case $a \sim b$, or $b ≲ a$ is false, in which case $a < b$. Conversely, the definitions of both $a < b$ and $a \sim b$ require $a ≲ b$ to be true.